# Why is every FD considered MVD?

Tags: database-normalization

As mentioned in [MVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency) that

> Every FD is an MVD because if X->->Y, then swapping Y's
>   between tuples that agree on X doesn't create new tuples.

I couldn't find the example for the above statement. Could somebody please provide an example which clarifies the above statement?

Comment: An FD is not a MVD. And FDs & MVDs make different kinds of starements/claims. But a FD implies a certain MVD.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try using the example from the [page you reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency). Say that unique combinations of courses and books  have only one lecturer:

> FD: (Course, Book) ->-> Lecturer

Now, swapping the Lecturer record between tuples for a given Course and Book combination does not modify the tuples (since the for a given Course and Book, the Lecturer is always the same). Hence:

> if X->->Y, then swapping Y's between tuples that agree on X doesn't create new tuples

Given this FD, the MVD still holds on the relation. In fact, the relation is now has fewer records than in the original example since as the FD is a 'stronger' dependency than the MVD.